# android: How to add button to the List view at top using base adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

In My application i want add the button to List View at the top. In this case it show the button at each list item instead of top. How to show at top only

**gender.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="Vertical"

 >

<Button
        android:id="@+id/b1
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"

 >

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />     

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Egender.java**

```
package com.Elgifto;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Egender extends ListActivity {

    private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
            // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);           
        }

        /**
         * The number of items in the list is determined by the number of speeches
         * in our array.
         *
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getCount()
         */
        public int getCount() {
            return GENDER.length;
        }

        /**
         * Since the data comes from an array, just returning the index is
         * sufficent to get at the data. If we were using a more complex data
         * structure, we would return whatever object represents one row in the
         * list.
         *
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItem(int)
         */
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        /**
         * Use the array index as a unique id.
         *
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItemId(int)
         */
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        /**
         * Make a view to hold each row.
         *
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
         *      android.view.ViewGroup)
         */
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls
            // to findViewById() on each row.
            ViewHolder holder;

            // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
            // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
            // by ListView is null.
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gender, null);

                // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
                // we want to bind data to.
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.cb=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);


                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
                // and the ImageView.
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
            holder.text.setText(GENDER[position]);
            //holder.text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            if(holder.cb.isChecked())
            {
                holder.cb.setChecked(false);
                String st=GENDER[position];
                System.out.println("String:"+st);
            }

                 return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {

            TextView text;
            CheckBox cb;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
    }

      private static final String[] GENDER = new String[] {
       "Male","Female"
    };
}
```

thanks

Comment: Do you want the button to scroll with the other ListView contents, or to be fixed at the top, and not actually "inside" the ListView?

Comment: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View, java.lang.Object, boolean))

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, you're using gender.xml as the layout for each row/item in the ListView.  So, you'll probably want to remove the Button declaration from gender.xml layout.

If you want the Button to be fixed above the ListView, then you probably want to edit the layout that declares the ListView to also declare the Button, assuming you have such an xml layout.

For example, the xml layout with the ListView might then look something like the following.

```
<LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
    <Button 
        id="my_button"
        width="wrap_content"
        height="wrap_content"
        layout_gravity="center"
        text="my button" />
    <ListView 
        id="my_listview"
        width="fill_parent"
        height="0dip"
        weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

(Note: This xml layout is not complete, and is missing pieces, such as the xmlns declaration.  For a more complete example, take a look at [Scrolling Text Above Buttons, Buttons Fixed At Bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447554).)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add header to the list view:

```
Button btn=new Button(this);
list.addHeaderView(btn);
```

this will make butten the first item of your listview

You can also make it not selectable by

```
list.addHeaderView(vbtn, null, false);
```

And sent an onItemClickListener.