# Including a Fixed Ad Below a List

Tags: android, admob, ads

I'd like to have a list of items with a fixed ad at the bottom of the screen.

This is the quick and dirty code I have so far (Does not include ads yet):

```
public class SoundBoard extends ListActivity {
private SoundManager mSoundManager;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.soundboard_item, CLIPS_STRINGS));



      ListView lv = getListView();

      mSoundManager = new SoundManager();
      mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
      mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.bad_seasons);
      mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.friend_at_airport);

      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            String selection;
            selection = (String) ((TextView) view).getText();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            if (selection == "Bad Seasons")
                mSoundManager.playSound(1);
            if (selection == "Friend at Airport")
                mSoundManager.playSound(2);

        }
      });
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)){
        finish();
    }
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)){
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

static final String[] CLIPS_STRINGS = new String[] {
    "Bad Seasons", "Friend at Airport"
};

}
```

I will probably use the Admob sdk.  What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `setContentView(R.layout.soundboard);` to your onCreate method, then create two XML files in layout:

soundboard.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
     android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <include layout="@layout/ad"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and ad.xml which will contain your layout for the ad.

Comment: In addition to this answer you have to add     AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView); and adView.loadAd(new AdRequest()); to load the ad.  Awesome answer thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new AdView from the AdMob SDK and set the new view as the footer for the list view. Something like:

```
lv.addFooterView(myAdMobView);
```

Comment: This works but note that it will inherit padding and margin of that ListView

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for example layout that does what you're asking about, take a look at [Scrolling Text Above Buttons, Buttons Fixed At Bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447554/scrolling-text-above-buttons-buttons-fixed-at-bottom).