# How to avoid video stop when I scroll the screen using youtube API in an android app?

Tags: java, android, video, youtube, youtube-api

I'm building an app for Android using the YouTube API. The video is in a scroll widget, and when I scroll and the video goes up or down the screen, it stops. I want the video to continue even though isn't in the screen. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

i went through the same problem, i open this question:

[Android YouTube API video pause when rotate screen or hide player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383209/android-youtube-api-video-pause-when-rotate-screen-or-hide-player)

see the comments to understand better. For the tests I did, the Youtube API knows when the player is not showing on the screen and just pause the video. As a workaround I changed my layout so that the player be fixed on the screen, just as is the official app from youtube.

I use this question as reference:
[Scrolling Text Above Buttons, Buttons Fixed At Bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447554/scrolling-text-above-buttons-buttons-fixed-at-bottom)